# GLSL Pixel shader operates only 0 texture unite

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glsl, shader

I'm trying to write a simple fragment shader, which should to mix 2 or more textures. I've written the test project on Qt 5.4, but for some reason it can't operate any textures which had bound to non zero unite.
it ignore any values in
  setUniformValue("tex*", *); (str. 83-90)
and any sampler2d always operates only texture which had bound to 0 unite.

whats wrong?

[Source of test project on Qt 5.4 available at bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/ibnz/shadertest)

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QOffscreenSurface>
#include <QOpenGLContext>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QOpenGLFramebufferObject>
#include <QOpenGLShader>
#include <QOpenGLTexture>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setMinorVersion( 2 );
    format.setMajorVersion( 4 );
    format.setProfile( QSurfaceFormat::CompatibilityProfile );
//    format.setProfile( QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile );

    QOpenGLContext context;
    context.setFormat(format);
    if(!context.create()){        
        qFatal("Cannot create the requested OpenGL context!");
    }

    QOffscreenSurface surface;
    surface.setFormat( format );
    surface.create();
    context.makeCurrent( &surface );

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    const float c_01SquareVertices[8] ={0.0f, 0.0f,
                                        1.0f, 0.0f,
                                        1.0f, 1.0f,
                                        0.0f, 1.0f};
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, c_01SquareVertices);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, c_01SquareVertices);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    int maxTextureUnits;
    glGetIntegerv ( GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, &maxTextureUnits );
    qDebug()<<"GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS" << maxTextureUnits;

    QImage texImg = QImage(":/tex/tex");
    QOpenGLTexture tex(texImg.mirrored());
    QImage texImg1 = QImage(":/tex/tex1");
    QOpenGLTexture tex1(texImg1.mirrored());
    QImage texImg2 = QImage(":/tex/tex2");
    QOpenGLTexture tex2(texImg2.mirrored());

    QString fsc =
            "uniform sampler2D tex;"
            "uniform sampler2D tex1;"
            "uniform sampler2D tex2;"
            "varying vec4 gl_TexCoord[];"
            "void main(void)"
            "{"
            "   gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex2, gl_TexCoord[0].yx * 2.0);"
//            "   gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex1, gl_TexCoord[0].xy) + texture2D(tex2, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);"
            "}";

    QOpenGLShader fsh( QOpenGLShader::Fragment, &context );
    fsh.compileSourceCode( fsc );

    QOpenGLShaderProgram pr( &context );

    pr.addShader( &fsh );
    pr.link();

    QOpenGLFramebufferObjectFormat fboFormat;
//    fboFormat.setInternalTextureFormat(GL_ALPHA32F);
    QOpenGLFramebufferObject fbo( 1000, 1000, fboFormat );
    fbo.bind();
        glViewport(0,0,fbo.width(),fbo.height());
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        tex.bind(0);
        pr.setUniformValue("tex", GLuint(1));

        tex1.bind(2);
        pr.setUniformValue("tex1", GLuint(2));

        tex2.bind(3);
        pr.setUniformValue("tex2", GLuint(3));

        pr.bind();

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
    fbo.release();

    QLabel w;
    w.resize(fbo.size());
    w.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(fbo.toImage()));
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Try moving `pr.bind()` to before the first `pr.setUniformValue` (after `glClear`)

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo you should move your comment to an answer

Answer (score 1):

In the C API for OpenGL, in order to use or modify an object, you must first bind it*.

Apparently, `pr.setUniformValue` does not bind `pr` before calling `glUniform` to change the uniform value. While a bit inconvenient and unintuitive, it's understandable; redundantly binding the same shader over and over has a performance overhead.

So just move `pr.bind()` to above where you call `pr.setUniformValue`.

---

*The *EXT_direct_state_access* extension allows you to modify objects without binding them, but requires a different API and is not guaranteed to appear in OpenGL versions before 4.5 (the latest).